# Counting and set operations

Tags: combinatorics

Assuming I have items that each have an optional set of attributes. i.e.

Item1[A], Item2[B], Item3[A,B], Item4[A,C], Item5[]

And I have the count of each occurrence, i.e.:

- A = 3 (A has occurred 3 times in the series above)
- B = 2
- C = 1

How can I find the count of items that have both A and B without iterating through the series?

If this is not possible based on the given inputs, what else do I need to keep track of to be able to answer the question "give me count of items that have A and B"?

Comment: basically you need to keep track of how many items have A and B. (or any other combination of 2, or if required more, properties)

Comment: That would be the "easy" way, but the issue is as the number of attributes grow, then the combinations of them also grow. I was trying to see if there is a smarter way.

Comment: I don't think so. At least if you need definite answers. (You could calculate some probabilities based on the information you already have though. Don't know whether that helps?)

Comment: Perhaps the approach taken by Wilf in "generatingfunctionology" <http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html> to handle the inclusion-exclusion principle is of some help?

Comment: I wonder if this can be done using an approach like De Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you're asking for something that's theoretically impossible.

Suppose we have $m$ sets, $a$ copies of $A$, and $b \leq a$ copies of $B$.  Let $c$ be the number of sets containing both $A$ and $B$.  Then $c$ can be anywhere from $b$ to $\max(0,a+b-m)$.  In general, therefore, we cannot determine $c$ from $a$, $b$ and $m$ alone.

*Complexity*:  Consider the situation where $m=2n$ and, for all $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ sets $2i-1$ and $2i$ between them contain exactly one copy of $A$ and exactly one copy of $B$.  There is no way to determine whether or not the $A$ and the $B$ are in the same set without looking at one of the sets ($2i-1$ and $2i$); complete knowledge of every other set would not help.  Hence, at least $n=\Omega(m)$ sets must be inspected.

However, if we had an Oracle that could tell us the number of sets $d$ that contain neither $A$ nor $B$, then $c=a+b-(m-d)$.

If you're happy with an estimate, you could try randomly sampling the sets.  If you take $N$ samples (with replacement), and find $x$ of them have both $A$ and $B$, then $x/N$ is an unbiased estimator of $c/m$.  However, if $c/m$ is quite small, then this method would also be impractical.

---

*Addendum*:  A practical method that springs to mind for this problem is "lists intersection", as used in search engines.  To illustrate, we store

- a list $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_s)$ of indices of the sets the contain A, and
- a list $(b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_t)$ of indices of the sets the contain B.

Then when we want to find the number of sets that contain both A and B, we compute $$\#\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_s\} \cap \{b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_t\}.$$  In general, we need to store a list for every possible "term" ($A$, $B$, etc.).  We store sorted lists, so $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_t$ which makes intersection faster.  An efficiently way to find the intersection is: [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for $a_1$ in the $(b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_t)$.  We then binary search for $a_2$ in $(b_r,b_{r+1},\cdots,b_t)$, where $b_r$ is the smallest element greater than $a_1$, and so on.  Generally, it's faster if $s \leq t$ (if not, then we can swap the sequences).

This can be sped up in various ways: caching, hardware, etc.  It falls into the field known as [information retreival](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval).

Comment: So I guess the next question should be, what's the minimum amount of counts do I need to keep to be able to answer the query? i.e. would it help to additionally keep count of non occurrences? I'm basically trying to see if I can avoid storing counts for ALL the combinations of ALL the attributes.